# Enabling gzip compression for JBoss cluster with mod_jk load balancer

Tags: apache, jboss, load-balancing, cluster-computing

We have a JBoss configured in cluster with Apache HTTP+mod_jk as a load balancer.
Do we need to configure anything on Apache side in addition to configuring compression in JBoss configuration for connector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In standard JBoss gzip compression could be enabled for HTTP connector, but not for AJP. AJP connector is used between Apache HTTP server and JBoss.

To enable gzip compression on Apache HTTP server side add following lines to mod_jk.conf before </VirtualHost>:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

This will enable gzip compression for specified mime types by means of mod_deflate output filter http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html.

Also uncomment following line in httpd.conf to turn on mod_deflate:

> LoadModule deflate_module
>   modules/mod_deflate.so

Comment: Is it possible to have the zipping done on each jBoss? I would like to keep the load balancer doing as little as possible?